# extending same layout twice in same page laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to use popups throughout my site. What I've noticed is that if you extend a template more than once on a page, the yields end up being rewritten by the last one. Any help?

```
<!-- layout.blade.php -->
@yield('section1')
div div div
@yield('section2')

<!-- popup1.blade.php -->
@extends('layout')
@section('section1')
    <p>here's some content about cats</p>
@stop
@section2('section2')
    <p>bla bla bla </p>
@stop

<!-- popup2.blade.php -->
@extends('layout')
@section('section1')
    <p>here's some content about monkeys</p>
@stop
@section('section2')
    <p> bla bla bla </p>
@stop
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I found a solution for the same by myself. In case anyone run into the same problem. Here is the solution

End each section with @overwrite and it will solves the problem.

```
<!-- layout.blade.php -->
@yield('section1')
div div div
@yield('section2')

<!-- popup1.blade.php -->
@extends('layout')
@section('section1')
    <p>here's some content about cats</p>
@overwrite
@section2('section2')
    <p>bla bla bla </p>
@overwrite

<!-- popup2.blade.php -->
@extends('layout')
@section('section1')
    <p>here's some content about monkeys</p>
@overwrite
@section('section2')
    <p> bla bla bla </p>
@overwrite
```

Comment: This link helps a bit a well: http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/244/stopping-injecting-content-into-a-section-and-overwriting